# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop, mariadb-10.4

I've setup 2 separate stacks with each one php + mariadb, via docker-compose.
The first one has mariadb listening on 3306 port :

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

I use -p flag to `build` and `up` the second project so that things don't get mixed-up :

`docker-compose -p project2 build && docker-compose -p project2 up`

**In the 2st project** I had to change the listening port for mysql :

```
ports:
  - "3308:3308"
```

...otherwise the docker daemon says 3306 is already taken, which I understand seems logical

which gives the following, using `docker ps -a` :

```
 3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3308/tcp
```

My problem is now that I cannot access the database from my windows host, I get this error :

**ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11**

I've tried several things in my mariadb2 Dockerfile

- adding `host.docker.internal` to */etc/hosts.allow*
- adding `bind-address=host.docker.internal` (tried 127.0.0.1 too, 0.0.0.0 too) to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- EXPOSE 3308

I've tried to open firewall rules too from and to 3308 port/TCP

What could I do next ?... takes me hours to figure out how to get thing working...

Comment: The second port in `ports:` always needs to be the "normal" port inside the container the process listens to, so change this to `3308:3306`.

Comment: thank you @DavidMaze, that is it :-) You save me a lot of pain...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error

Lost connection to MySQL server at ‘reading initial communication packet’, system error: 0

In my case i stopped already installed MySQL and that is it!
[image]